# List.Sort alleging that my IComparer is inconsistent

Tags: c#, sorting, generics

I have a list of tblDetail objects. tblDetails have txtTracked, a string. I want to sort based on this property. so I do:

```
switch (sortby)
{
    //...
    case "Tracked Y/N":
        list.Sort((lhs, rhs) => {
            return lhs.txtTracked.CompareTo(rhs.txtTracked);
        });
        break;
    case "Tracked Y/N-desc":
        list.Sort((lhs, rhs) => {
            return -lhs.txtTracked.CompareTo(rhs.txtTracked);
        });
        break;
    //...
}
```

except sometimes txtTracked is null. Ok, fine, so I do:

```
switch (sortby)
{
    //...
    case "Tracked Y/N":
        list.Sort((lhs, rhs) => {
            string toCompare = lhs.txtTracked;
            if (toCompare == null)
                toCompare = "";
            return toCompare.CompareTo(rhs.txtTracked);
        });
        break;
    case "Tracked Y/N-desc":
        list.Sort((lhs, rhs) => {
            string toCompare = lhs.txtTracked;
            if (toCompare == null)
                toCompare = "";
            return -toCompare.CompareTo(rhs.txtTracked);
        });
        break;
    //...
}
```

The regular ascending sort works fine, but for some reason when I do this with the descending sort on the same set of data, I get a null reference exception on lhs in "Tracked Y/N-desc". so I do:

```
switch (sortby)
{
    //...
    case "Tracked Y/N":
        list.Sort((lhs, rhs) => {
            string toCompare = lhs.txtTracked;
            if (toCompare == null)
                toCompare = "";
            return toCompare.CompareTo(rhs.txtTracked);
        });
        break;
    case "Tracked Y/N-desc":
        //for some reason this sort adds null into the list. wat.
        list.Sort((lhs, rhs) => {
            if (lhs == null)
                return 1;
            if (rhs == null)
                return -1;
            string toCompare = lhs.txtTracked;
            if (toCompare == null)
                toCompare = "";
            return -toCompare.CompareTo(rhs.txtTracked);
        });
        list.RemoveAll(d => d == null);
        break;
    //...
}
```

only now I get a new error:

```
Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare() method returns inconsistent results. Either a value does not compare equal to itself, or one value repeatedly compared to another value yields different results.
```

what gives? It works fine sorting one way but not the other. How does C# decide that my sort function isn't good enough, and how can I make it right?

and as an aside, why is null getting added into my list when I call sort?

Comment: If both lhs and rhs are null - it should return 0 and not 1 like now.

Comment: Negating the result of `CompareTo` isn't a reliable way to reverse a sort; it doesn't handle `int.MinValue` correctly.  You should reverse the order of the operands to reverse the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, you've been lucky that the ascending sort didn't throw a null reference exception. Or should that be, you've been unlucky that it hasn't come to your attention.

One (or more) of your objects is null. It just happened to turn up on the rhs when you used ascending sort, and lhs on descending sort. It's ok to have rhs == null since the `CompareTo` method takes care of that. But if lhs == null, you get an exception.

There is already a null-safe method which allows either/both lhs and rhs to be null: the static [`String.Compare(String, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx). You can use this method together with the [null-safe navigation operator ?.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/) as follows:

```
list.Sort((lhs, rhs) => { return String.Compare(lhs?.txtTracked, rhs?.txtTracked); });
```

for the ascending sort, and

```
list.Sort((lhs, rhs) => { return String.Compare(rhs?.txtTracked, lhs?.txtTracked); });
```

for the descending sort.

Comment: @Adam: note that the above also avoids [the incorrect use of negation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820101/list-sort-alleging-that-my-icomparer-is-inconsistent#comment72752439_42820101) to reverse the sort order.

Comment: But with this approach, with the operator `?.`, we will get all the entries where the `tblDetail` itself is `null` mixed among all those entries where the `tblDetail` is a "good" instance (i.e. non-null) that just happens to have its `.txtTracked` member equal to `null`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen good point. The OP needs to make a decision as to how a null lhs should compare with a null rhs.txtTracked (when rhs is not null). In this answre, they are treated as equal. Whether that's good or not depends on the problem domain.

Answer (score 2):

You:

```
    list.Sort((lhs, rhs) => {
        if (lhs == null)
            return 1;
        if (rhs == null)
            return -1;
        // more cases
    });
```

This will not work because if *both* comparands are `null`, it will always return positive one. So the sorting algorithm can never get it right. Once it swaps two `null` because they are in the wrong order, they are still in the wrong order, for example.

What ever you come up with, if `x` compared to `y` is not zero, it must be opposite in sign of `y` compared to `x`.

Instead you could do:

```
    list.Sort((lhs, rhs) => {
        if (lhs == null || rhs == null)
            return Comparer<object>.Default.Compare(rhs, lhs);
        return string.Compare(rhs.txtTracked, lhs.txtTracked);
    });
```

In the case where one or both is `null`, I simply compare them as objects. That will work. You could write it in another way also:

```
    list.Sort((lhs, rhs) => {
        if (lhs == null || rhs == null)
            return (rhs != null).CompareTo(lhs != null);
        return string.Compare(rhs.txtTracked, lhs.txtTracked);
    });
```

This way used the fact that `false` is smaller than `true`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to switch variables for the desc.

```
list.Sort((lhs, rhs) => {
            return (rhs.txtTracked ?? "").CompareTo(lhs.txtTracked ?? "");
        });
```

Comment: This still blows up if `rhs` itself (or `lhs` itself) is `null`. So I do not think it answers the question. Even when your code does not blow up, it sorts all entries where `txtTracked` is `null` together with those where `txtTracked` is `""`, all mixed. This might not be what we want. `null` and `""` are not normally considered equal.